# RVM install gives error Unrecognized option: --autolibs=3 on OSX Lion

Tags: ruby, osx-lion, rvm

I got a new MacBook Pro with Lion on it, and I'm trying to run:

```
\curl -#L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=3 --ruby
```

according to https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

The command gives me:

```
Unrecognized option: --autolibs=3
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that on the home page of the rvm site I seen that there was a diffrent install script.

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails --autolibs=enabled
```

Install worked with no issue.

Looks like the install page is just out of date.